# Does the external CSS file of partial also start with '_' in asp.net?

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-core, partial-views

I'm new to *asp.net* and have few questions.

I have a module with `Index.cshtml` along with `_Partial1.cshtml` and `_Partial2.cshtml` in the same folder.

1. Should I create individual external CSS file for each HTML file or use common CSS file per module?
2. If former, then does CSS file name of each partial also start with `_`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create individual CSS file for each HTML file and you can also write all css code in `Index.cshtml`.

There is a new feature called `CSS Isolation` in `.Net6`. `CSS isolation` simplifies an app’s CSS footprint by preventing dependencies on global styles and helps to avoid styling conflicts among components and libraries. CSS Isolation is enabled by default for ASP.NET Core 6.0 Projects.

So if you wanna create individual CSS file for each HTML file, You can use CSS isolation. Just create a css file called `<ViewName>.cshtml.css`, And it should be in the same folder as the view.

In your project, You can create CSS file called `_Partial1.cshtml.css` and `_Partial2.cshtml.css`, Then The project structure will become：

[image]

**If you are using .Net5, You can try this code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/P1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/P2.css">


//......other code........
<div id="Pattial1">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Shared/_Partial1.cshtml")
</div>

<div id="Partial2">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("/Views/Shared/_Partial2.cshtml")
</div>
```

**CSS file**

```
#Pattial1 h1{
    color : red
}

//......
```

Comment: thanks. Any option for core 5v?

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04, Net5 doesn't support `CSS Isolation`, So CSS file's name doesn't need to start with `_`, I suggest you to upgrade to .Net6, Because .Net5 is out of support now.